# how to get data for each row of the mat table asynchronously

Tags: angular, api, asynchronous, angular-material, mat-table

I am using a mat-table ,

each row of the table has eight columns , the data source given to the table fills only 4 columns in each row of the table , for the remaining 4 columns of each row we have to request another api , In its api, the id of each row must also be sent

Can anyone guide me?

Comment: Can you provide some anonymised code, please? What do you have so far?

Answer (score 1):

you need create a data with all the columns. So You should use rxjs operators: switchMap, forkJoin and map

Imagine you has a service that has two functions

```
  list()  //return an observable of array of items
  read(id) //return an element given an "id"
```

you can create a function in your service that return the list, but complementary with all the properties of the "read"

```
  readFull()
  {
    return this.list().pipe(switchMap((res:any[])=>{
        return forkJoin(res.map((x:any)=>this.read(x.id).pipe(
          map((more:any)=>({...x,...more})
        ))))
    }))
  }
```

It's a bit complex, I try to explain. First imagine you has an object

```
x={id:1,name:"one"}
//when you make
this.read(x.id).pipe(
   map((more:any)=>{
      return {...x,...more}
   })
)
```

You get an object with all the properties of "x" and all the properties that received from this.read()

Well, imagine you don't has a single object else an array of object. you can transform the array of object in an array of observables

```
res=[{id:1,name:"one"},{id:2,name:"two"}]

res.map((x:any)=>the before function
```

When we has an array of observables we can join all in one using forkJoin

```
forkJoin(..the array of observables..)
```

Well, first we get the "list", but we are not interesting in the "list" else the observable create by the forkjoin. For this we need use switchMap

You can see the concept in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-taavzw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdata.service.ts) when I "simulate" read and list using "of"