# How to wait until each of my http get requests are served so that I can use the response of each of the request and use them in the same iteration?

Tags: angular, typescript, spring-boot, http-get, steam-web-api

I am designing an application using Angular and Springboot to show game details.

I am currently fetching a list of games from the steam API (link: http://api.steampowered.com/ISteamApps/GetAppList/v0001) and storing the appIDs of the games in a list called appIds[]. In another function getNewReleasedGames(), for every game, I am making a call in a for loop to another API (link: https://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails?appids=10) which has all the details I want. The problem is even before my HTTP request gets served, the code below is executing and I am getting "Undefined" for any attribute of my response I have received but when I am logging the output on the console, the entire data is present.

I am completely new to the concept of promises,then,async/await. I have searched various posts regarding this but could not find a solution to my problem. I want my for loop to run sequentially, store the get method response and then proceed for another iteration. Is there anyway to do it? Also, this seems to work fine without the for loop i.e. when I give a single game as an input.

**My_Component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { waitForAsync } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { GetAppListService } from '../get-app-list.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-game-details',
  templateUrl: './game-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./game-details.component.css']
})
export class GameDetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private getAppListService : GetAppListService) { }

  appIds:number[] = []
  
  
  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

  public apps()
  {
    //the below request returns a list of 139715 games from the public API
    this.getAppListService.gameList().subscribe(
      (data:any) => {

        console.log('THe obtained list of games is ',data)
        console.log(data[0].applist.apps[1].name)

        for(var i=0;i<139715;i++)
        {
          this.appIds[i] = data[0].applist.apps[i].appid
        }
        console.log("length of the appIds is ",this.appIds.length)
        console.log("AppIDs are ",this.appIds)
    
      },
      (error:any) => {console.log('Error obtaining games!',error)}
    )
  }


  public getNewReleasedGames()
  {
    console.log("array values are ",this.appIds)
    for(var i=0;i<5;i++) //currently trying to print the details of 5 games
    {
      // console.log("i value is " , this.appIds[i]);
      
      this.getAppListService.newRelease(this.appIds[i]).subscribe(
        (data:any) => {

          var id = this.appIds[i];
          
          console.log("data obtained is " , data); //this prints the data
          console.log(data[id]); // this prints undefined but prints the data for a single item when there is no for loop present
        },
        (error:any) => {
          console.log('Error obtaining game details!',error)
        }
      )
    }
    // console.log(this.responses.length)
  }



}
```

The following is my service file.
**service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class GetAppListService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }


  baseUrl = "http://localhost:8080"

  public gameList()
  {
    return this.http.get<any>(`${this.baseUrl}/games`,{
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },})
  }

//The below function is used to fetch the game detail per iteration from the component class.
  public newRelease(appid:number)
  {
    return this.http.get(`${this.baseUrl}/newReleaseGames/${appid}`,{
      headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },})
  }

}
```

The following is my back-end code for obtaining the game details.
**Controller.java**

```
@GetMapping(value = "/newReleaseGames/{appid}")
    private Object newlyReleasedGames(@PathVariable long appid) {

        System.out.println("Obtained app id is " + appid);
        String url = "https://store.steampowered.com/api/appdetails?appids="+appid;
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

        Object games =  restTemplate.getForObject(url,Object.class);
        System.out.println(games);

        return games;
    }
```

The terminal output in the Spring boot also does not print the appid followed by the game details. It prints a set of appIds and then set of game details. I am not understanding how to synchronize my calls sequentially.

Kindly help me solve this problem. Any tips/suggestions/advices are welcome.

Comment: forget promises and await!! use switchMap and forkJoin, see e.g. this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67218302/how-to-get-data-for-each-row-of-the-mat-table-asynchronously/67219675#67219675)

Answer (score 0):

Try to search and read about asynchronous code execution to understand the code flow.

In a sense when the http request is ready your code inside `subscribe` executes and while it is not ready other code outside of `subscribe` continues to execute serially line by line. Whenever the http request response becomes ready the code execution is transferred to the block of `subscribe`. When this finishes it continues from where it was left from before.

So the requirement that you have would be fulfilled simple if you moved the call for the second http request into the subscribe block code of the first http request.

Comment: How do I get to stop the execution of my code until my HTTP request is served first?

Comment: Search and read for async/await functionality.

Comment: This however should not be done as you don't want to block all the application until 1 request is finished. Use either what I said or use observable methods like switchMap